# Counting total rows and grouping by a column in mysql

Tags: mysql

So i've been looking at this one for a while and I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a mysql table with the following format and sample data:

```
ID, Customer, Time, Error Code, Duration

1,Test1,00:12:00,400,120
2,Test2,00:14:00,404,60
3,Test1,00:15:00,404,120
4,Test2,00:17:00,503,120
5,Test1,00:19:00,400,60
6,Test1,00:20:00,400,60
7,Test2,00:21:00,503,60
```

I need the results to have the customer name, total number of rows per Customer name, the error codes per customer, then the number of errors per customer and then sum the duration. So for the above results I would want to get:

```
Test1, 4, 400, 3, 360
Test1, 4, 404, 1, 360
Test2, 2, 404, 1, 240
Test2, 2, 503, 2, 240
```

The problem i am having is when i group by the error code, the count for the number of rows and the sum of the duration is also grouped by that error code. I need the total count of rows and duration for the customer not the total count of rows and duration for the customer per error code.

Please let me know if I need to include anything else or if i'm super confusing which I probably am.

THank you in advance for all the help!

Comment: What that `1` in your result means?

Comment: The 1 in the result is the count of the number of error codes. So for test1 it had a total of 1 400 error codes

Comment: Can you add some more data so the result get more obvious? Right now scais and my  query only count how many Test1 are. Those are the `2` isnt?

Comment: I added a few more. Just to make it more clear i'll explain what each column in the results should be
Column 1: Name of customer
Column 2: Total number of records for that customer
Column 3: Each error code per customer:
Column 4: Total number of that error code per customer
Column 5: Total sum of duration for that customer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need group by to get the calculated columns

```
 SELECT Customer, COUNT(*) as total_count, SUM(duration) as total_duration
 FROM yourTable
 GROUP BY  Customer
```

and

```
 SELECT Customer, Error, COUNT(*) as error_count
 FROM yourTable
 GROUP BY  Customer, Error
```

Then join back to you table

```
SELECT t1.Customer, 
       t2.total_count, 
       t1.error, 
       t3.error_count, 
       t2.total_duration
FROM yourTable as t1
JOIN (
     SELECT Customer, COUNT(*) as total_count, SUM(duration) as total_duration
     FROM yourTable
     GROUP BY  Customer
     ) as t2
  ON t1.Customer = t2.Customer
JOIN (
     SELECT Customer, Error, COUNT(*) as error_count
     FROM yourTable
     GROUP BY  Customer, Error
) as t3
 ON t1.Customer = t3.Customer
AND t1.Error = t3.Error
GROUP BY t1.Customer
       , t1.Error
```

Comment: Check now, you need two subquery to get those calculations.

Comment: With this i'm getting ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name 'Error'

Sorry I had a typo. Trying it now. THank you

Comment: I keep getting duplicate rows like the following:

Test1 2026 404 1997 594068
Test1 2026 404 1997 594068
Test1 2026 404 1997 594068

Comment: I just had to add a group by t1.customer, t1.error_code and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Was my fault there was a comma instead a dot. And yes was a missing `GROUP BY` at the end

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join on a subselect with the sum for customer
You could use a join on a subselect with the sum for customer

```
select a.customer, a.error, t.num_row, t.duration 
from my_table   a
inner join ( 
    select  customer, count(*) as num_row, sum(duration) duration 
    from my_table 
    group by customer 
  ) t on t.customer  = a.customer
```